# Telerik Rad Controls - Accessibility API

Tags: telerik

Does anyone have any idea if Telerik provides any accessibility APIs for its RAD controls? I am automating an application that has loads of RAD controls and none of the tools or MSAA seem to be working on it. Any help/info is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a decent amount of digging around the internet, it seems Telerik is providing accessibility to its controls from release 2012.3.1017 onward. [This article](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/getting-started/accessibility-support.aspx) is of help.
Also checked out with the latest controls and UIAVerify, the Patterns for the controls are accessible now.